# Alternative DataSource of ComboBox and the like instead of Datatable to save memory

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datatable

I'm just wondering how can i save up memory. Usually, i use Datable for binding datasource of ComboBox and Datagridview. I'm wondering if there's an alternative way such as collection/Dictionary and how can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom line, when you have objects in the memory, It doesn't really matter in what structure you hold them.
The sum of occupied memory will be the sum of you object's size + the overhead of the holding structure.

If you are worried about the amount of memory in use, I think it is safe to assume that the holding structure size is negligible (again, a safe assumption if you are using a common structure and not a badly designed one).

When you select an object to hold your data, I would suggest choosing it by what will make your run time better and coding easier.